# JS not properly hiding/showing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a webform for my wife. She works in an insurance agency and is wanting a web based form for gather info to process quotes. Some background - I will not have access to a server for this and will need to print all details in this form when the user is done inputting information. I want the user to be able to select different quote types on the first div, then be directed through each related div (i.e. you don't gather info for a renters quote if they own their home, you're just taken through home quote)

Currently, whenever you're on quoteselection div and hit next, it shoots you to the last div (autoquote) instead of going to the second div (customerinfo)
Once you hit next, you can also never go back to the quoteselection div without reloading the page.

I've also had issues where touching the JS will make it so neither function works at all.

Can someone help me with this please? I'm fairly new to JS, but have worked with C# in the past and it's honestly been a while since I've dabbled with HTML. Google has not been able to help me out on this one either. Please let me know if there's any additional info you may need regarding this post

```js
/*eslint-env es6*/

function nextForm(){
    //obtain different forms and store to local variable
    var quoteselection = document.getElementById('quoteselection');
    var customerinfo = document.getElementById('customerinfo');
    var autoquote = document.getElementById('autoinsquote');
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    var backBtn = document.getElementById('backbtn');
    
    
    
    //Check which form currently on
    if(quoteselection.style.display == 'block')
        {
            //show / hide different forms based on current location
            alert('you are now going to customer info');
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
            
        }
    else if(customerinfo.style.display == 'block')
        {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
    else(autoquote.style.display == 'block')
    {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'none';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'block';
        }
}
function backForm() {
    //obtain different forms and store to local variable
    var quoteselection = document.getElementById('quoteselection');
    var customerinfo = document.getElementById('customerinfo');
    var autoquote = document.getElementById('autoinsquote');
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    var backBtn = document.getElementById('backbtn');
    
    //Check which form currently on
    if(quoteselection.style.display == 'block')
        {
            //show / hide different forms based on current location
            backBtn.style.display = 'none'; 
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'block';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
    else if(customerinfo.style.display == 'block')
        {
            backBtn.style.display = 'none';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'block';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        } 
    else(autoquote.style.display == 'block')
    {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
    padding:5px;
}
.quotetype {
    text-align: center;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
.quotetype input:button {
    margin:50px;
}
.customerinfo {
    
}
#nextbtn {
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
#quoteselection {
    display:block;
}
#customerinfo {
    display:none;
}
#autoinsquote {
    display:none;
}
#backbtn {
    display:none;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Quote Sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<h2>Welcome to our new Interactive Quote Sheet V1.0</h2>

<div id="quoteselection" class="quotetype">
<form class="quotetype">
<input type="checkbox" id="autoquote" name="autoquote" value="Auto">
<label for="autoquote">Auto</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="homequote" name="homequote" value="Home">
<label for="homequote">Home</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="rentquote" name="rentquote" value="Renters">
<label for="rentquote">Renters</label><br><br>

</form>
    </div>

    <div id="customerinfo">
<form class="customerinfo">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="First Name"><br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br> 
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name = "lastName" value="Last Name"><br>
    <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob"><br>
    <label for="streetadd">Street Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="streetadd" name = "streetadd"><br>
    <label for="city">City</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
    <label for="state">State</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>
    <label for="zip">Zip Code</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip"><br>
    
    <br>
    <label for="driverslicense">Drivers License Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="driverslicense" name="driverslicense">
    <label for="dlstate">State</label>
    <input type="text" id="dlstate" name="dlstate" value="MO"><br>
    <label for="social">Social Security Number</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="social" name="social" value="XXX-XX-XXXX">
    <br>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label><br>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="XXX-XXX-XXXX"><br>
    <label for="email">Email Address</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="john.smith@email.com"><br>
    <p>Do you own or rent your residence?</p>
    <label for="own">Own</label>
    <input type="radio" id="own" name="own" value="own">
    <label for="rent">Rent</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rent" name="rent" value="rent"><br>
    
    <label for="autopay">Autopay</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="autopay" name="autopay"><br>
    <label for="paperless">Paperless</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="paperless" name="paperless"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="autoinsquote">
    <form class="autoquote">
        <p>Let's gather some information about your current policy</p>
        <p>Is the garaging address the same as the address provided previously?</p>
        <label for="addsameyes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="addsameyes" id="addsameyes">
        <label for="addsameno">No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="addsameno" id="addsameno"><br>
        
        <label for="people">How many people are in the household?</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="people" name="people" value="2"><br>
        
        
        
    </form> 
    </div>
        
    <button id="backbtn" name="back" onclick="backForm()">Back</button>
    <button id="nextbtn" name="next" onclick="nextForm()">Next</button>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `...style.display == "block"` will only check inline styles. If you have an external stylesheet you can do this:

```js
/*eslint-env es6*/

function nextForm(){
    //obtain different forms and store to local variable
    var quoteselection = document.getElementById('quoteselection');
    var customerinfo = document.getElementById('customerinfo');
    var autoquote = document.getElementById('autoinsquote');
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    var backBtn = document.getElementById('backbtn');
    
    
    
    //Check which form currently on
    if(window.getComputedStyle(quoteselection).display == 'block')
        {
            //show / hide different forms based on current location
            alert('you are now going to customer info');
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
            
        }
    else if(window.getComputedStyle(customerinfo).display == 'block')
        {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
    else(window.getComputedStyle(autoquote).display == 'block')
    {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'none';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'block';
        }
}
function backForm() {
    //obtain different forms and store to local variable
    var quoteselection = document.getElementById('quoteselection');
    var customerinfo = document.getElementById('customerinfo');
    var autoquote = document.getElementById('autoinsquote');
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    var backBtn = document.getElementById('backbtn');
    
    //Check which form currently on
    if(window.getComputedStyle(quoteselection).display == 'block')
        {
            //show / hide different forms based on current location
            backBtn.style.display = 'none'; 
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'block';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
    else if(window.getComputedStyle(customerinfo).display == 'block')
        {
            backBtn.style.display = 'none';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'block';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'none';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        } 
    else(window.getComputedStyle(autoquote).display == 'block')
    {
            backBtn.style.display = 'block';
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
            quoteselection.style.display = 'none';
            customerinfo.style.display = 'block';
            autoquote.style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

Comment: That does fix an issue where the alert wasn't popping up, but it still throws the user to the last "page" instead of "page 2"

edit: I added alerts to each div swap and am seeing that when you're on page 2 trying to go to page 1, it somehow triggers the nextForm() function so you get both alerts and it keeps you on page 2.